# How to configure postgresql to use multiple cores?

Tags: postgresql

How can I configure postgresql to use multiple cores in a single machine , is it automatically uses it ?

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#How_does_PostgreSQL_use_CPU_resources.3F

Comment: You could do some tests to see it working.

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL automatically uses multiple cores to support multiple database connections, if you have multiple cores.  No further configuration is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres allocates one process per client, and, generally speaking you will only see that process go to 100% of 1 of your cores.  To increase throughput you need to use more clients/connections.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/connect-estab.html

Comment: good point, apart from 8.2 being a bit outdated.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even see that was the version that came up in Google.  The text is the same even in the current 9.3 dev version: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/connect-estab.html